# Denegar creación de cuentas con rol de administrador Spring Boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Actualmente estoy desarrollando una aplicación back-end con Spring Boot, en la que he implementado un sistema de autenticación con roles de usuarios. Para realizar la creación de cuenta de administrador he hecho un petición post desde Postman asignando este rol.

Mi pregunta es, cualquiera que quisiera realizar una petición mediante este tipo de aplicaciones, como por ejemplo Postman, podría asignarse a sí mismo el rol de administrador ¿Cómo puedo añadirle seguridad a este tipo de peticiones para que esto no llegue a suceder?

AuthConroller.java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

WebSecurityConfig.java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dependera mucho de tu implementacion/configuration actual de Spring. Si agregas un poco mas de informacion, alguien podria ayudarte de una mejor manera =)

Comment: Perfecto, ajuntaré capturas de mi configuración. Si necesitas algún tipo de información la proporcionaré sin problema.

Comment: Muy bien. Una mejora adicional: Cuando colocas codigo, es preferible que lo coloques como texto con formato de codigo, en vez de imagenes. =B

Comment: Disculpa las molestas, en muchas ocaciones no me lo permite debido a la ponga cantidad de código en comparación con la te texto. Muchas gracias!